# What is the most effective increased "dosage" or level of the Tabata HIIT protocol?

Tags: hiit, tabata

I've had good results following the standard Tabata Protocol (20s "max" and 10s rest).

***Update**:

I do this protocol 5 days a week and mt bike pretty hard the 6th day.
In the "work" cycle on the Tabata protocol I can reach "max" in about 15s.*

But I got to the point where it takes me 15s or so to reach *max*
This is on an exercise bike "out of the saddle".  I could probably go a little harder by "running" rather than "jumping" onto each pedal but I find that tough to coordinate on a bike.

(I am not meaning to humblebrag here: I'm the slowest person on my weekly group Mt. Bike rides. I cardio is my limitation).

I'm currently on 25s /12s rest  x 12 Reps.
But.... I'm not completely wiped at the end (super tired for sure). And on each work rep I don't reach the "poop my pants" point .  And I think I should be.
On my mt. bike rides I find that I can now go "all out" for longer (maybe 1-2 minutes before reaching that "poop point", up from about 30 s or so).  But  the guys I'm riding with can just keep at that speed for 10 minutes. (I just want to keep up so I'm not slowing everyone down :)

**What is the best way to increase it?**

- Increase the *work* length?
- Decrease the *rest*?
- Increase the # of *Reps*?

And let me know whether you've measured positive results for yourself or if there is some citation of someone else who has measured it.

The [Gibala Regimen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_interval_training#Gibala_regimen) and others I've seen which are designed to be less intensive increase the Work and rest cycle  and reps to:   60 w/ 75 r x 8-12 Reps. So *maybe* that's my answer.

Comment: How often do you Tabata? Doing it daily helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you can go harder by "running" rather than "jumping" then you should do that.

Anything that you can do for 1 to 2 minutes isn't "all out". You need to find a way to go all-out, 100%, in that 25 seconds. Messing with the edges of the protocol--5 seconds less rest or more work effort--isn't going to solve this central issue. Increase or decrease the stationary bike resistance until you find the sweet spot where you can go all-out.

If you absolutely can't go all-out on a bike, then try some other exercise where you are certain that you *can't* go any faster or get any more reps in. Maybe that's running, maybe it's air squats, maybe it's punching a heavy bag.

Or, switch to a different protocol that understands that you won't be going at 100%. The Gibala Regimen sounds fine. But also consider non-biking modes of exercise: sport-specific abilities can actually *interfere* with improving your cardio. If it's metabolic conditioning you want (even it it's conditioning for biking), and you can't sufficiently challenge yourself with biking, then bodyweight or dumbbell high-intensity intervals could better help you hit maximum cardio intensity.